# Bash scripting, Expect, and interfacing with a remote CLI

Tags: linux, bash, shell, expect

I am working on a cool little project for my 3 year old. It is a small box with a telephone handset in which, he can walk up an push either the "Dad" button or the "Mom" button. It will then call one of our cell phones.

I used to be s SW developer but never for Linux, and am not familiar with Bash scripting. Under the hood of the box is a raspberry Pi running IncrediblePBX and trunked to a google voice number. I am interfacing to the GPIO pins for the buttons using the GPIO commands. MY script is just a continuous while loop checking GPIO inputs and once it senses an input, will attempt a call.

For the SIP client I am using linphonec, a command line SIP client. It works really well for placing a call. Once started you get to the linphonec command prompt "linphonec>", where you just "call xxxyyyzzzz".

Now that I am trying to put the linphonec control into a bash script I am running into some issues. For starters, I am currently trying to use an embedded Expect script in the bash script to listen for and respond to the linphonec prompts. I have not gotten this to work yet, but should eventually get it working. But the bigger question I now have is, How to I continue to monitor the GPIOs (loop in the bash script) if I am in this expect script? IF I exit the Expect script, can I jump back in to the linphonec CLI to terminate the call using "Terminate" (If the handset is placed on the cradle)? Should I run the linphonec in a separate console Windows and interact through an alternative method? Can I run it in the background using the "&" and still send commands to it?

Comment: (1) I don't advise `expect` as the right tool for the job. (2) However, if you want to run it (or anything else) in the background while being able to write to its stdin and read from its stdout, that's a job for a [coprocess](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/keywords/coproc).

Comment: ...really, though, there's no shortage of SIP libraries for Python or other, higher-level languages (and since you're proposing to use a TCL interpreter to run `expect`, a Python interpreter is the same class of overhead).

Comment: That said, the reason the above is commentary rather than an answer is that frankly, I'm not sure this question is a good fit for the site as currently asked. If you focused on just one question ("Can I run a command in the background and still send commands to it?"), and included some code demonstrating what you're trying to do (ideally, a [mcve]), that would be a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

Charles Duffy - Using a coporocess was the correct approach for me.  It worked perfectly in my BASH script and kept everything simple.  Thank you.